# Как получить погоду из координат пользователя? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Ситуация такая. Пользователь хочет узнать погоду через TelegramBot. Жмет на кнопку, я получаю его координаты и с помощью модуля **`pyowm`** пытаюсь получить погоду в его регионе.

Как это реализовать?

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

import pyowm

owm = pyowm.OWM('API', language = 'ru')

bot = telebot.TeleBot("API")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def text(message):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=False)
    button_geo = types.KeyboardButton(text="Отправить местоположение", request_location=True)
    keyboard.add(button_geo)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет! Нажми на кнопку и передай мне свое местоположение", reply_markup=keyboard)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["location"])
def location(message):
    if message.location is not None:
        print(message.location)
        print("latitude: %s; longitude: %s" % (message.location.latitude, message.location.longitude))
        lat = message.location.latitude
        lon = message.location.longitude
        print ("\n"+str(lat)+"\n")
        print ("\n"+str(lon)+"\n")
        observation_list = owm.weather_around_coords(lat, lon)

        observation = owm.weather_at_place(observation_list)
        print ("\n\n"+str(observation_list)+"\n\n")
        print ("\n\n"+observation+"\n\n")
        w = observation.get_weather()

bot.polling()
```

Comment: А почему не определять город и по нему уже получать погоду через апи OpenWeatherMap?

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 Может подскажешь как это сделать?

Comment: Определите город сначала. Вам отвечали уже, какими средствами это можно сделать.

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 В том то и проблема, что я не знаю как определить город.

Answer (score 1):

возможно код убогий, но это было давно, я только учился

```
owm = pyowm.OWM(owm_token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['city'])
def cmd_city(message):
    send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введи город')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(send, city)
    log(message)


def city(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ищу погоду в городе {city}'.format(city=message.text))
    time.sleep(2)

    data = message.text
    observation = owm.weather_at_place(data)
    w = observation.get_weather()
    wind = w.get_wind()
    temp = w.get_temperature('celsius')
    hum = w.get_humidity()

    wnd = json.dumps(wind, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    tmp = json.dumps(temp, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    pwnd = json.loads(wnd)
    ptmp = json.loads(tmp)
    winds = pwnd['speed']
    tmp = ptmp['temp']
    tmpx = ptmp['temp_max']
    tmpn = ptmp['temp_min']

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     'В  {city}: \n  Сейчас: {tmp}°C \n  Максимум: {tmpx}°C \n  Минимум: {tmpn}°C \n  Ветер: {wind} м/с \n  Влажность: {humidity}%'.format(
                         city=message.text,
                         tmp=(tmp), tmpx=(tmpx), tmpn=(tmpn),
                         humidity=(hum), wind=(winds)))
```

Answer (score 0):

у тебя был почти готово все там только немного надо было переделать, ну и ответ тебе нужно будет просто распарсить

```
import pyowm
from telebot import TeleBot
from telebot import types

from config import config

bot = TeleBot(config["token"])
owm = pyowm.OWM('API', language='ru')


@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def text(message):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=False)
    button_geo = types.KeyboardButton(text="Отправить местоположение", request_location=True)
    keyboard.add(button_geo)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет! Нажми на кнопку и передай мне свое местоположение", reply_markup=keyboard)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["location"])
def location(message):
    if message.location is not None:
        print(message.location)
        print("latitude: %s; longitude: %s" % (message.location.latitude, message.location.longitude))
        lat = message.location.latitude
        lon = message.location.longitude
        print("\n",lat,"\n")
        print("\n",lon,"\n")
        observation_list = owm.weather_around_coords(lat, lon)

        observation = owm.weather_at_coords(lat,lon)
        print("\n\n"+str(observation_list)+"\n\n")
        print("\n\n"+str(observation)+"\n\n")
        w = str(observation.get_weather())
        bot.reply_to(message, w)
```